# notify-send in C code

Tags: c, popup

How can I call `notify-send` from C code with a message stored in my string ?

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
   system("mount something somewhere");
   system("notify-send message");
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just send the string as a parameter to `system()`.

For example:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    char command[100], msg[100];

    strcpy(command,"notify-send ");
    strcpy(msg,"\"Hello World\"");
    strcat(command,msg);

    system(command);
    return 0; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    system("notify-send Test \"Hello World\"");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If this code does not work for you be sure that **notify-send** command work in command line. if the command does not work in even command line, try install it first `sudo apt-get install notify-osd`